# How to repair a shed door that is rotting at the base?

Tags: doors

We've neglected our shed for a long time.  I put in some wood filler many years back but we were abroad for a few years and then had other priorities when we returned.

It now looks like this, (tennis ball for reference)

[image: shed door]

I was thinking of cutting back the middle pieces with a jigsaw and replacing with a two inch plank.

Does that make sense?  Is there a better way to repair a door or should I just scrap and replace?

Comment: It's hard to say not knowing much about the structure of the door. Please provide more photos or a better description.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed a door like that.

It rots because it gets wet, that's probably due to rain splashing on it.

There's a horizontal plank on the other side of the door that holds the vertical planks together. If it is rotten, change it. Then place an identical horizontal plank on the front side of the door. That makes a sandwich with the old door in the middle, using screws.

Screws don't hold into rotten wood, but with two new planks on either side of the sandwich, no problem. The screws will go into the new plank.

Now if you find the new planks lack support on the bottom, or the wood is just too rotten and gets squished, you can cut the bottom of the door to have enough space to insert a shim (as the center slice in your sandwich). But don't cut too much of the vertical planks, otherwise there will be nothing left to hold the horizontal planks in place.

The horizontal plank should have its top edge cut at an angle so any water flows down on the ground instead of pooling.

Then some caulk in the holes, to prevent water from getting in.

It's been about 10 years, and it's still in good shape.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the OP cut back the rotten vertical face and install a horizontal face in it's place, or that he simply add a horizontal on top of the existing vertical pieces? I'm just a bit unclear on your description.

Comment: I've edited the answer.